# ORA-08103: object no longer exists: This error is occuring for Oracle Procedure returning Refcursor from MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, oracle10g, mybatis

When calling a Stored Procedure in Oracle returning refcursor I am getting an error

```
2011-05-10 03:36:23 DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener [DEBUG] After test method: context [[TestContext@3a363a36 testClass = AccountActivityServiceTest, locations = array<String>['classpath:/com/bnymellon/pwb/pfdetails/service/test/test-application-context.xml'], testInstance = com.bnymellon.pwb.pfdetails.service.test.AccountActivityServiceTest@6d2c6d2c, testMethod = getData@AccountActivityServiceTest, testException = org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists

### The error may involve com.bnymellon.pwb.pfdetails.persistence.AccountActivityMapper.getAccountActivityData-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists

; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [8103]; ORA-08103: object no longer exists
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists
```

I am using Spring MyBatis integraton project. the version of MyBatis is 3.0.4

I can see the Procedure is being executed. The logs are below.

```
2011-05-10 03:36:16 PreparedStatement [DEBUG] ==>  Executing: {call PWMWI.PAM_TRANSACTION_PKG.ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} 
2011-05-10 03:36:16 PreparedStatement [DEBUG] ==> Parameters: 1987(Integer), 5627(Integer), null, null, 2010-01-01(Date), 2010-12-31(Date), All Asset Classes(String), [All, PYR](String), (String), null
```

My Mapper XMl is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.bnymellon.pwb.pfdetails.persistence.AccountActivityMapper">
    <select id="getAccountActivityData"
        parameterType="com.bnymellon.pwb.pfdetails.common.AccountActivityDTO"
        statementType="CALLABLE">
        {call PWMWI.PAM_TRANSACTION_PKG.ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY(
        #{userInstance,mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER},
        #{accountGroupId,mode=IN,
        jdbcType=INTEGER},
        #{accountId,mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{accountId,mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{startDate,mode=IN,
        jdbcType=DATE},
        #{endDate,mode=IN, jdbcType=DATE},
        #{assetClass,mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{transactionType,mode=IN,
        jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{cusipId,mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{ticker,mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{domainList,mode=OUT,jdbcType=CURSOR,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,resultMap=aaDataMap})}
    </select>

    <resultMap type="com.bnymellon.pwb.pfdetails.domain.AccountActivity"
        id="aaDataMap">
        <result column="TICKER" property="ticker" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="CUSIP" property="cusIp" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="SECURITY_NAME" property="securityName"
            jdbcType="VARCHAR"></result>
        <result column="ASSET_CLASS" property="assetClass" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="TRADE_DATE" property="tradeDate" jdbcType="DATE" />
        <result column="SETTLE_DATE" property="settleDate" jdbcType="DATE" />
        <result column="DESCRIPTION" property="description" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="RECORD_TYPE" property="description" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="ACCOUNT_NUMBER" property="accountNumber"
            jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="QUANTITY" property="shares" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="LONG_DESC" property="transDesc" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="PORT_NUM" property="indicator" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
        <result column="AMOUNT" property="amount" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

I am using MyBatis version 3.0.4 and my Oracle driver jar is ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar

The IN and OUT parameters and their data types for Procedure are as below:

```
P_USER_INST           NUMBER        IN     
P_GROUP_ID            NUMBER        IN 
P_ENTITY_ID           CHAR          IN 
P_ENTITY_NAME         VARCHAR2 (30) IN   
P_START_DATE          DATE          IN      
P_END_DATE            DATE          IN     
P_ASSETCLASS          CHAR          IN        
P_TRAN_TYPE           CHAR          IN   
P_PRIMARY_ASSET_ID    VARCHAR2      IN        
P_TICKER              VARCHAR2      IN   
P_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_CUR  REF CURSOR    OUT
```

My DTO in Java is below(omitting the setter/getter methods)

```
private Integer userInstance;

private Integer accountGroupId;

private String accountId;

private Date startDate;

private Date endDate;

private String transactionType;

private String ticker;

private String cusipId;

private String assetClass;

private List<AccountActivity> domainList;
```

Any help is highly appreciated as I am clue less what is going on and really stuck on this.

Answer (score 4):

I've just had a similar issue with .net rather than Java.

my problem related to the fact that the cursor opened based on a global temporary table.  when we changed the GTT to "on commit preserve rows" from "delete rows" it worked fine.

see if that works for you?

Comment: I was forgetting to set autocommit to false, when I changed that configuration it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a corruption, physical or logical, in a table or data file.
Check with your DBA for recovering the data. You can find steps on how to recover corrupted data from an Oracle table at http://24x7dba.blogspot.com/2011/08/salvage-data-from-corrupted-oracle.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-8103 "object no longer exists"

Error: ORA 8103

### Text: object no longer exists

Cause: The object has been deleted by another user since the operation began.
Action: Remove references to the object.

ORA-8103 is reporting that a SQL statement found a block that no longer belongs to the object referenced in the statement.
Cause
ORA-8103 is caused by an invalid block type. The block header has an invalid block type or the block type inside the block is not expected; e.g. a data block (Type=6) was expected
but the actual block information is not a data block (Type!=6).
ORA-8103 is also caused by an unexpected data_object_id where it is changing for the involved objects while the affected SQL statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

After Struggling one week finally I fixed the Issue:

Solution:  Most likely that a cursor is opened based on a global temporary table(GTT), which had been created with ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS option. And the cause of the ORA-08103: object no longer exists error is commit statement that followed right after the delete statement. DBA team didn't agree to change the GTT
as on commit preserve rows so finally I added code base in Java Service Layer[Implementing the Spring - Programmatic Transaction]

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO {
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
   private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
      this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }
   public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
      this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
   }
   public void create(String name, Integer age, Integer marks, Integer year){
      TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
      TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

      try {
         String SQL1 = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
         jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL1, name, age);

         // Get the latest student id to be used in Marks table
         String SQL2 = "select max(id) from Student";
         int sid = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForInt( SQL2 );

         String SQL3 = "insert into Marks(sid, marks, year) " + "values (?, ?, ?)";
         jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL3, sid, marks, year);

         System.out.println("Created Name = " + name + ", Age = " + age);
         transactionManager.commit(status);
      } 
      catch (DataAccessException e) {
         System.out.println("Error in creating record, rolling back");
         transactionManager.rollback(status);
         throw e;
      }
      return;
   }
   public List<StudentMarks> listStudents() {
      String SQL = "select * from Student, Marks where Student.id=Marks.sid";
      List <StudentMarks> studentMarks = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, 
         new StudentMarksMapper());

      return studentMarks;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was related to a global temporary table.
In the table DDL, I changed from "on commit delete rows" to "on commit preserve rows" and the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Create your global temporary table as below when you are creating it.

`CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_name(col-1 type, col-2 type, ...) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`